# Function returns None- Python

Tags: python

I call an exchange API. When I try to put it as a function, it returns `None`:

```
def getCurrentExchange(source, target):
    """The function takes the source - source and target currency - target and extract the rate as of now"""
    url = 'https://api.exchangerate.host/convert?from=source&to=target'
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    xchng = data['result']
    return xchng 
print(getCurrentExchange("EUR", "USD"))
```

When I call the API without wrapping it as a function, I get the rate:

```
url = 'https://api.exchangerate.host/convert?from=USD&to=EUR'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
data['result']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add the line `return xchng` at the end of your function. Any function without a `return` statement will return `None`

Comment: You aren't returning anything from your function, just printing.

Comment: Unfortunately, even if I add return xchng and then, wrap getCurrentExchange("EUR", "USD") to print(getCurrentExchange("EUR", "USD")), I would still get None

Comment: @eponkratova Update your code with a return in your function and request a re-open since it does not solve your issue

Comment: I think it has sth to do with the type - the rate is float. When I use the function, the returned type is NoneType , when I just call the API, the type is float.

Comment: @eponkratova This has to do with the URL you use in the function. You should use built-in string `format` to install value in your url: `"my_api_url = "https://api.exchangerate.host/convert?from={}&to={}".format(source, target)`. This will solve your issue

Comment: And indeed, it did solve the problem! Thank you, @Jib. I guess we cannot do anything with the closed status

Comment: @eponkratova I can't, indeed ..

Answer (score 0):

you need a return value.

```
def getCurrentExchange(source, target):
    """The function takes the source - source and target currency - target and extract the rate as of now"""
    url = f'https://api.exchangerate.host/convert?from={source}&to={target}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    return data['result']
getCurrentExchange("EUR", "USD")
```

Comment: No, if I use def getCurrentExchange(source, target):
    """The function takes the source - source and target currency - target and extract the rate as of now"""
    url = 'https://api.exchangerate.host/convert?from=source&to=target'
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    xchng = data['result']
    return xchng
print(getCurrentExchange("EUR", "USD")) it still returns None

Comment: with f-strings you can fill your values into the url